# Using Castle Windsor in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I want to add a logger to the Windows Form Application by using Castle IOC.

I registered the logger like below:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());

        container.Register(Component.For<ICommonLogger>().ImplementedBy(typeof(CommonLogger)).LifeStyle.Singleton);
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new EAE_Automation.COM.LoggerResolver(container.Kernel));

    } 
}
```

Then another form of the application, I tried to use the logger as property but It comes null to the program.

```
namespace Test.KNXManagement
{
    public partial class Test: Form
    {
        public ICommonLogger Logger { get; set;} 

        public Tunneling()
        {
            Logger.Info("Testing.......................");

        }

    }
}
```

I think I am missing an important point here

Comment: Move the `ICommonLogger` dependency into the constructor of the `Test` form and resolve this form from the container. This allows you to find out misconfigurations when you resolve the form.

Comment: It still doesn't work, though you changed Logger from private field to public property? How did you register your Test class and how is it resolved?

Comment: Have you tried `Logger = container.Resolve<ICommonLogger>();` after adding it to the container?

Comment: @aevitas I also tried that one it says = " Can't create component 'CommonLogger' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'CommonLogger' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'System.Type' which was not registered. "

Comment: @RyuKaplan Is `ICommonLogger` an interface or a class?

Comment: @aevitas its interface

Comment: @RyuKaplan Alright. I just tried with the code I pasted below and it worked perfectly fine for me, give it a go. Also, are you using Castle Windsor from NuGet?

Comment: @Steven Thanks for your opinions. Thats give me the sign to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also register the Form class to resolve sub dependencies.

```
    container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<Form>());
```

Then also run the application as below

```
    Application.Run(container.Resolve<Test>());
```

Thats solved my problem.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The following code, based on yours, works perfectly fine for me:

```
    private static IWindsorContainer _container;
    static Program()
    {
        Debug.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());

        _container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());

        _container.Register(Component.For<ICommonLogger>().ImplementedBy(typeof(CommonLogger)).LifeStyle.Singleton);
    }

    private static ICommonLogger Logger { get; set; }
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Logger = _container.Resolve<ICommonLogger>();

        Logger.Write("Text");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public interface ICommonLogger
    {
        void Write(string str);
    }

    public class CommonLogger : ICommonLogger
    {
        public void Write(string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
```

The output of the program in the console is `Text`.

Comment: I should resolve the logger from the "Form". Maybe thats the case for me that differs from your scenario

Comment: So how are you resolving it in the form?

Comment: I think, I should register all windows forms first. If I register them  then the logger can be resolved. Maybe I should open another question for it.

Comment: @Ryu Kaplan: Of course, the Logger within your Form can ONLY be automatically resolved, if you get the Form from the container too. If you used new Form(), where should the container come into play?